# A template was not provide for npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: node.js, templates, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new react-app and also use npm start on an existing react app project.

When I try to create a new react-app I get the following error:

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

I did a lot go googling and found that many have been having this error. I've tried many different solutions, but nothing has worked.

I globally uninstalled react, cleaned the cache folder, update node, npx, and npm. I've followed to the steps to various blogs. Any additional help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: what command are you using to create a react app?

Comment: also, what happens when you run `npx create-react-app -V` vs `create-react-app -V`